# Output array object value if multiple values from different objects of the same group of array are selected

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress

I am creating an AJAX feature for a form that asks for 3 inputs - BEDS, BATHS, FREQUENCY. I want the output to be the PRICE. So when the user does the input, it only outputs the corresponding price of the Array I created.

PHP CODE SNIPPET (ARRAYS):

```
 $pricing = array (
    array ('frequency' => "one", 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1 , 'price' => 90),
    array ('frequency' => "one", 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 1.5 , 'price' => 113),
    array ('frequency' => "one", 'beds' => 1 , 'baths' => 2 , 'price' => 113),
    array ('frequency' => "one", 'beds' => 2 , 'baths' => 2.5 , 'price' => 135),
    array ('frequency' => "weekly", 'beds' => 3 , 'baths' => 3 , 'price' => 135),
    array ('frequency' => "weekly", 'beds' => 3 , 'baths' => 3.5 , 'price' => 158),
    array ('frequency' => "biweekly", 'beds' => 4 , 'baths' => 4 , 'price' => 158),
    array ('frequency' => "biweekly", 'beds' => 4 , 'baths' => 4.5 , 'price' => 180),
    array ('frequency' => "monthly", 'beds' => 5 , 'baths' => 5 , 'price' => 180),
    array ('frequency' => "monthly", 'beds' => 5 , 'baths' => 5.5 , 'price' => 203),
    array ('frequency' => "monthly", 'beds' => 6 , 'baths' => 6 , 'price' => 203)
);
```

I managed to pass the values from what was inputted but my function does not work. Apparently I can echo (echo $selected_frequency_id;) the values that was selected from my form but I can not echo the PRICE. Is my function incorrect? I can't find anything wrong with the foreach loop. Please see code below:

PHP CODE CONTINUATION:

```
function ajax_update_price() {

$selected_bed_id = $_POST['bedID'];
$selected_bath_id = $_POST['bathID'];
$selected_frequency_id = $_POST['frequencyID'];

//echo $selected_frequency_id;

    foreach( $pricing as $element ) {
        if( $element['frequency'] == $selected_frequency_id && $element['beds'] == $selected_bed_id && $element['baths'] == $selected_bath_id) {
             echo $element['price'];
             break;
    }
 } 

    wp_die(); 
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ajax_update_price() {
  global $_POST;


$selected_bed_id = $_POST['bedID'];
$selected_bath_id = $_POST['bathID'];
$selected_frequency_id = $_POST['frequencyID'];


foreach( $pricing as $element ) {
    if( ($element['frequency'] == $selected_frequency_id) && ($element['beds'] == $selected_bed_id) && ($element['baths'] == $selected_bath_id)) {
         echo $element['price'];
         break;
   }
  } 

wp_die(); 
}
```

but i have more beautiful solutions:

```
 $pricing["one"]["1"]["1"] = 90;
 $pricing["one"]["1"]["1.5"] = 113;
 $pricing["one"]["1"]["2"] = 113;
 $pricing["one"]["2"]["2.5"] = 135;
 $pricing["one"]["2"]["2.5"] = 135;
 $pricing["weekly"]["3"]["3"] = 135;
 $pricing["weekly"]["3"]["3.5"] = 158;
// and so on, i think you understand how to continue
```

and new function will be:

```
function ajax_update_price() {
  global $_POST;


$selected_bed_id = $_POST['bedID'];
$selected_bath_id = $_POST['bathID'];
$selected_frequency_id = $_POST['frequencyID'];

if ($pricing[$selected_frequency_id][$selected_bed_id][$selected_bath_id])
    print $pricing[$selected_frequency_id][$selected_bed_id][$selected_bath_id]

  wp_die(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! will try this!

Comment: Sorry, newbie here. I copied exactly your first suggestion and it still doesn't work. I also copied your second suggestion and removed my original array and still not working.